# How to get an empty parameter from an url like "example.com/id//"?

Tags: url, symfony1, query-string

I am using symfony 1.0 and below is the URL which displays the news description.

```
http://news4u.com/search/news/id/344158/css//act/n
```

In the above URL value for CSS is missing and the URL is supposed to be as below

```
http://news4u.com/search/news/id/344158/css/n/act/n
```

When I use `$this->getRequestParameter('css')` to get the value of css, I get it as 'act' and if the do the same for 'act', I get empty value.

```
$getRequestParameter('css')=act
$getRequestParameter('act')=<EMPTY>
```

I am getting values for above parameters for the metioned URL.

I want to get value of 'act' in above URL. How to get that?

Comment: How do you build this url? I think you should always put some default value to css, to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: There is search functionality for searching news. for every search result, based on its category, dynamically css value will get assigned.. 

But is there any way of getting act value. If not in framework, atleast using core PHP ?

Comment: It will be harder than giving a default value to css (even if it's generated).

Comment: how if the url is exploded by '/' and getting value of act ? does it make sense...?

Comment: it can make sense but it's a more a patch for a bad behavior than *the* way to do it.